# How to find which column/columns caused the miss match in my except query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Column caused the miss-match for the Except query

```
select
    showID,
    startDate,
    startTime,
    synopsis ,
    talents,
    titleName,
    titleNo,
    titleType
from
    Master_table
except
 select
    showID,
    startDate,
    startTime,
    synopsis ,
    talents,
    titleName,
    titleNo,
    titleType
from
    stg_master
```

This returns me the row which does not match with 2nd query, But how do I find out which column caused the miss-match

Comment: Is `ShowID` unique?

Comment: No Unique ID available

Comment: Simplify the problem. Perhaps 3 columns will do fine. Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: It could be all columns... Completely different rows.

Comment: @sidharthasarangi . . . Sample data and desired results would help.  There is no such thing as a single column that causes the mismatch -- `except` is simply saying that at *every* row differs by at least one column value.